# django - Cannot use admin to add custom user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I used the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to create a custom user model. Everything works fairly well, but when I try to add a new user using the admin interface, I get this error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/main/user/add/
no such table: auth_user
```

My custom user model is in the `main` app, so there is no `auth_user` table in the database, but a `main_user` one. I'm not sure why Django is trying to save this new entry in the wrong database..

I did redefine the UserAdmin model and the corresponding add/change forms.

I have this in my `models.py`:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # custom stuff..
```

This is in `admin.py`:

```
from main.models import *

class UserCreationForm(forms.UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)

class UserChangeForm(forms.UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form     = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the cause but did you set the custom auth model in your settings (AUTH_USER_MODEL = "....", see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)?